# understanding scoping in javascript - using the same temporary element in two different functions

Tags: javascript, scoping

I was working on a jQuery plugin where I did something like this:

```
 function MyPlugin() { ... }

 MyPlugin.prototype = {
     foo: function() { ... },
     bar: function() { ... },
     baz: function() { ... }
 }
```

Now the `foo` function ran a loop, which called the `bar` function:

```
 foo: function() {
     for (i in this.values) {
         var result = this.bar(this.values[i]);
     }
 },


 bar: function(value) {
     var res = '';
     for (i in value) {
         // do something
     }
     return res;
 }
```

Now please ignore what the functions are actually doing here, the focus is the loop itself. I've noticed that, since I'm using `i` inside `bar` - it *changes* the value of `i` for `foo` as well.

I've read about [javascript scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) before, but still the example really confuses me. Why is `i` slipping between functions like that? How does it make any sense? I ended up just using a different variable, but I'm wondering what's the *right* way to avoid this sort of problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is not only slipping between the functions, it's everywhere. As you haven't declared the variable in the functions, you are using a global variable.

Declare the variable in each function, and each function will have its own variable and leave the global scope alone:

```
foo: function() {
  for (var i in this.values) {
     var result = this.bar(this.values[i]);
  }
},


bar: function(value) {
  var res = '';
  for (var i in value) {
     // do something
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: I kind of intuitively guessed that using `var` would solve it, but isn't it weird that if you don't declare it it would automatically turn into a global variable?

Comment: @yuvi: The script engine couldn't know if you wanted to create a local variable or if you wanted to use a global variable. If it's not declared locally, it has to be global. If it would create a local variable if there doesn't exist a global variable, then the code would behave differently depending on the situation, which would be hard to follow.

Comment: But normally, using an undeclared variable means an error. When using a `for (i in obj)` loop that's somehow fine and automatically a global? I find that very inconsistent, no?

Comment: @yuvi: Javascript was originally intended for doing small tasks in the browser, not building large applications. It was more important that you could just put something in a variable and use it somewhere else without worrying about scope, than programming concepts like encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks, it really clears things up for me. It seems that javascript went further than anyone imagined it would.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not prefix the initial assignment of the `i` variable with the `var` directive, JavaScript creates a global variable, which is shared between the foo and bar function calls. Instead, you want:

```
for (var in in this.values) { ... }
```

If `this.values` is an Array, don't use a for-in loop. Use a plain vanilla for loop to avoid looping over the "length" property as well:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) { ... }
```